# Find Numbers Equal to or Greater than 1 using regex

Tags: regex

I'm not a developer or scripter.  I can't contribute much to this forum but I do use it to get guidance for my staff of developers.  That's my disclaimer because the last time I was on this site, someone reamed me out for asking questions and not contributing.  For this, I do apologize.

If anyone is willing to assist, or at least give me a kick-start, how would I find the version of a file if the version has #.#.###; i.e., 6.1.3890?

So, my goal is to find a number that is equal to or greater than 1 and equal to or greater than 389.  I am only concerned with the digits after the first l'.' and the second '.'

Thanks to any and all.

Comment: Should it really be `regex`, though? This is a major cinch in Python, for example.

Comment: What program are you using with your regexp?

Comment: you should provide a sample from a the text file you're working on , because the `regex` depend totally on how text appears in file and also specify which language you're using

Comment: We're using a product called BladeLogic and I'm creating something called a compliance rule.  I don't think they use anything but regex but I could be wrong.  The file name of concern is msxml6.dll.  The first digit will always be '6' the next number after the '.' can be 0 but I already have a condition because we know what the next set of numbers will be; I'm using starts with.  Now, there are other versions out there like 6.1.xxx, 6.2.xxx, 6.3.xxx and that is it.

Comment: not very clear, should `6.2.0` be accepted or not?

Comment: So, here's what I've come up with for looking at msxml6.dll file version of 6.3.7601.18431:

6\.[1-9]\.[0-9]\d{3,}\.*.*)

Comment: Yes!!  6.1.0, 6.2.0, 6.3.0 would all be accepted.

Comment: 6.3.7601.18431 does not match the template `#.#.###`, neither does `6.1.3890`.  Did you mistype your question?

Comment: No, I guess I was just trying to say that for my first condition, 6.1.3890.xxxxx, I need to see if it is the same or higher.  There are five other digits after the 0 but I don't care about those.  
 
I did make one mistake, though. As far as the other versions, we have 6.10.xxxx.xxxxx, 6.20.xxxx.xxxx, etc. So, if I see a 6.1 or 6.2, or a 6.3, I don't care what succeeds the 6.1, or 6.2, or 6.3 either, because we know these file version work with our product.

Answer (score 1):

A regex for a number greater than `389`:

```
(39[0-9]|[4-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+)
```

A regex for a number greater than `1`:

```
([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)
```

A combined regex for version above `6.1.389`:

```
(6\.1\.(39[0-9]|[4-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+)|6\.([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)\.[0-9]+|([7-9]|[1-9][0-9]+)\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)
```

Non zero numbers should not start with a `0`.

If the version number format is limited to `#.#.###` or possibly fewer digits for the last part, the regex can be simplified to:

```
(6\.1\.(39[0-9]|[4-9][0-9][0-9])|6\.[2-9]\.[0-9]+|[7-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]+)
```

Comment: Hello everyone, I want to thank you for assisting me (my developers) in going in the right direction.  Although what you've provided me did not fix or give us what we needed, it definitely helps us tremendously.  For that, I thank all of you.  I did just find out from our vendor (BMC) that this is Java's regex so maybe that's why what has been provided, has not worked.  Needless to say, my developers are scurying around with all this new information you've provided.